# Responsive dotted borders with icons images in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make this similar design using HTML and CSS, I'm also using Bootstrap 3 because I need to make it responsive, as you can see there is dotted borders with different colors and icons images:

[image]

So this is what I did:

```css
.content{width: 100%;position: relative;height: 800px;}
        .section01{width: 70%;float: left;height: 600px;justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;}
        .section02{width: 30%;float: left;height: 600px;justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;}
    .context h1{color: #009164;font-size: 38px}
    .context p{color: #273994;font-size: 20px;}
    .context{width: 640px;margin: 0 90px 0px auto;}
    .border_box{padding-top: 50px;padding-left: 30px;padding-bottom: 50px;width: 850px;margin: 0 90px 0px auto;position: relative;}
    .b1{position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    border-left: 6px dotted #009164;
    border-top: 6px dotted #009164;
    height: 180px;
    width: 380px;
    border-radius: 12px;}

    .b2{position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-left: 6px dotted #273994;
    border-bottom: 6px dotted #273994;
    height: 72px;
    width: 380px;
    border-radius: 12px;}

    .img01{position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 62%;
    left: 10px;}

    @media (max-width: 768px){
        .section01{float: none;width: 100%;display: block;    height: auto;}
        .section02{float: none;width: 100%;display: block;    height: auto;}
        .context{width: 100%;}
        .border_box{width: 100%;}
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content">
    <div class="section01">
        <div class="border_box">
            <div class="b1"></div>
            <div class="b2"></div>
            <div class="img01"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/PX9ORs5.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
            <div class="context">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section02">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/S8mdCoO.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I don't know how can I make the beginning and the last past keeping the border radius:

[image]

I'm also trying to do it responsive.

How can I solve it?

I'd like your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these changes to your CSS

Demo:
https://codepen.io/esanazizi/pen/dyGzrzO

[A fork of esnezz's pen with rounded-border](https://codepen.io/xyz_code/pen/zYrdQJy)

```
   .b1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      border-left: 6px dotted #009164;
      border-top: 6px dotted #009164;
      height: 180px;
      width: 380px;
      border-top-left-radius: 12px;
    }
    
    .b2 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      border-left: 6px dotted #273994;
      border-bottom: 6px dotted #273994;
      height: 72px;
      width: 380px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    }
    
    .b1::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: -81px;
      right: 0;
      border-left: 6px dotted #009164;
      height: 72px;
      width: 5px;
    }

    .b2::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -81px;
      right: 8px;
      border-left: 6px dotted #273994;
      height: 72px;
      width: 5px;
    }
```